# Calendário com slide nos dias do mês

Tags: calendar, slide

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pessoal sou aprendiz, imaginei um projeto e queria muito realizar, preciso conseguir dar vida a este calendário, se bem que só posso chamar de ideia de calendário.

Onde no meio fica o dia atual há principio, na esquerda o dia anterior, e na direita o dia posterior. com setas de next e previous tipo slide nos dias do mês, onde no  meio é o dia selecionado que fica em destaque tipo um zoom, ano, dia da semana e mês neste estilo.

Talvez seja até fácil fazer, mas já estou a 3 semanas procurando tutoriais e nada, fico pulando de JavaScripit para PHP e o que consegui ate agora foi muito poco ou quase nada.

```css
body{
    color: #333;

}

.product-tabs {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-tabs {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
    border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #d51335;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

.tab-pane{
    padding: 10px;
}

.tab-control .previous-button, .tab-control .next-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
}

.tab-control .previous-button{
    left: 10%;
}

 .tab-control .next-button{
     right: 10%;
 }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Previous & Next button</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h2>Calendário<br/><small>2017</small></h2>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="teste tab-content text-center">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                <h3>Quarta</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
                <h3>Quinta</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                <h3>Sexta</h3>
            </div>                    
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 product-tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="tes"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">13</a></li>
                    <li class="tes active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">14</a></li>
                    <li class="tes"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">15</a></li>                                       
                </ul>

                


                <div class="tab-control">
                    <a class="previous-button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <a class="next-button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x fa-fw"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" id="">
                <h3>Dezembro</h3>
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
        

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.next-button').click(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            //trigger the click on the tab same like we click on the tab
        });

        $('.previous-button').click(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            //trigger the click on the tab same like we click on the tab
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Meio com vergonha de por o que fiz mais é o jeito, coloquei apenas 3 dias de exemplo no código, porque não faço ideia de como associar o calendário real,mas a ideia é que os outros dias fiquem ocultos, acho que deu para entender. se alguem poder pelo menos dizer qual caminho seguir agradeço.

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Vc tem que aprender uma linguagem e nela montar o que vc quer fazer. Programação envolvendo calendário envolve algumas coisas. Seu código não mostrou nada. De onde vc tah puxando o calendário? Sugiro que monte o layout primeiro (parece que já tem alguma coisa) e a partir daí procure uma linguagem de programação para pegar as datas.

Comment: Que vergonha rsrs, mas é assim mesmo no começo.De ante mão agradeço a atenção. 
Há muitos tutoriais na internet que ajudam muito, por eles consigo pegar bem data tanto por PHP quanto por javascript, mas o problema é a exibição na index, pegar de lá também consigo tanto por GET, POST, ElementeByID, mas repito, mostrar lá especificando onde será exibido ainda é confuso pra mim. Bem como desmembrar as partes da data, já que as funções mostradas nos tutoriais por ai, mostram apenas o dia em que estamos e os calendários são módulos prontos. um input tipo date por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que você entenda como outros plugins de calendário funcionam e tente aplicar ao seu projeto, como exemplo, sugiro o [datepickerbootstrap](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). No entanto você tem que saber bastante de javascript, sugiro começar estudando do básico ao avançado antes de prosseguir.
(Tive que publicar uma resposta pois não tenho acesso a comentários)

Comment: Tem razão, o que mais me atrapalha é a ansiedade de já programar, o problema é que não estou fazendo a pergunta direito, consigo pegar data do sistema em php e js, já consegui fazer um calendário por tabela também direto na index, mas não estou conseguindo entender como desmembrar as partes especificando onde cada parte sera exibida por exemplo, já que a ideia parece pedir isso porque é tipo um slid em círculos, há não ser que sou um jumento que não ver que o que eu quero fazer é apenas CSS. rsrsr estou desconfiando disso.

Mas obrigado estou olhando a documentação que me recomendou.